# Are name server's data public, and how to retrieve them if they are?

Tags: dns

Knowing the IP of a name server, is it possible to retrieve the "associations" that this server does between numerical IPs and domain names?

For example, a name server who would manage the domain name "google.com" would associate it with the IP 8.8.8.8.

I doubt that this data is free access, but how do you know if a specific name server "shares" its data or not? And if it does, how do you technically access it?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a security question. This appears to be a standard DNS query question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associations between IP and hostnames can be obtained easily if the name server is not configured properly, allowing zone transfer to systems other than the intended DNS servers. Zone transfer can be done using `nslookup` in Windows or `dig` available for Linux. If zone transfer is not possible, then the next option is dictionary based attack to find the hostnames present in the zone file.

To perform zone transfer you can refer https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10452/dns-zone-transfer-attack

Comment: @JesvinGeorge this is what i was looking for, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, if I understood your question correctly, is called a [reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).

A quick google search brings up a [web service](https://remote.12dt.com/) that does that quite on the top. There are others to choose, too.

If you are - because your example is one of googles domain servers - after the IP of the name servers responsible for a domain, the Whois entry of the domain shows their IP addresses.

You can then retrieve the zone information for that zone from that DNS-Server using `dig` for example.

Comment: I don't think OP asks for `in-addr.arpa` reverse DNS lookup. And I also highly doubt the service you linked to would give any sensible results. Let's try `security.stackexchange.com` -->  `104.16.119.182` --> `(unable to resolve 104.16.119.182)`.

Comment: I tried w/ ops `8.8.8.8`, which yielded the expected result, @techraf